# L'emploi de « tour » et « tournure » selon les contextes ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, synonymes, lexique

J'utilise indistinctement (le) [*tour*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tour/2) et (la) [*tournure*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tournure) quand j'écris.

> *Tournure* :
>  Manière de s'exprimer, forme donnée à un énoncé dans sa construction, sa syntaxe. (TLFi)
>   [...]
>   *P. méton.* Groupe de mots dont la construction est figée ou déterminée.
>   (TLFi)
>
> *Tour* :
>  Manière spécifique de s'exprimer, d'être exprimé; ce qui est exprimé. (TLFi)

On présente aussi différents syntagmes associés (voir les vedettes respectives). On a aussi *tour/tournure de [phrase](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/phrase/0)*.

> [...] considérant que l'emploi de *dessein* appartient semble-t-il à des
>   tours plus ou moins figés dans des locutions [...]

- Dans la phrase qui précède, considère-t-on que l'un ou l'autre est
  plus adéquat ou meilleur et pourquoi ?
- Indépendamment du fait qu'ils soient identifiés comme des synonymes
  (au TLFi) et de la phrase précédente, peut-on préciser si certains
  contextes se prêteraient mieux à l'emploi de l'un ou de l'autre, présenter des exemples le cas échéant, et donner des informations sur leur fréquence d'utilisation ?

Comment: Je ne puis pour l'instant trouver les mots pour exprimer pourquoi j’utilise [l’un](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A13100+tour) ou [l’autre](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A13100+tournure), mais il semble y avoir quelque chose, car je ne changerais, encore aujourd’hui, à peu près aucune de mes contributions passées pour l’autre terme. Un premier niveau d’explication serait que *tour* est davantage lié à l’aspect ou à la forme, *tournure* à la manière.

Comment: Mais ça n'explique pas tout. Je semble en certains cas privilégier *tournure* simplement parce que *tour* me semble inélégant. Peut-être que le terme est un peu vieilli, et que son emploi se limite de plus en plus à certaines circonstances particulières, à certains **tours** dont je ne distingue pas encore clairement les limites?

Comment: @Montéedelait C'est peut-être le [suffixe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ure) qui conditionne une partie de la perception... Je dirais qu'avant de participer au site je n'employais pas _tour_, je pense que c'est le LBU qui m'a peut-être influencé...

Answer (score 2):

Cette réponse arrive peut-être un peu tard, mais je vous encouragerais à utiliser *tournure* dans votre phrase. Je trouve cela non seulement bien plus naturel, mais également bien plus commun. Le vrai problème que pose l'utilisation de *tour* est l'ambiguïté due aux autres définitions bien plus connues du mot. Malgré le fait que les deux mots puissent être considérés comme synonymes, je suggèrerais l'emploi de *tournure* à chaque fois.

Comment: Voir mon commentaire sous la question. Pour l'homonymie d'accord en général mais dans la phrase en exemple la confusion est impossible. J'aime bien la différence, si on me dit que l'un est plus naturel et plus commun, je vais sans doute préférer l'autre...

Comment: @Survenant9r7 En effet, dans la phrase que vous avez citée, la confusion est impossible, mais néanmoins votre lecteur risque de s'arrêter brièvement sur le mot. Vous risquez de manquer de clarté, surtout si vous en faites une habitude. Je suis d'accord avec Montée de lait que tour semble manquer d'élégance dans de nombreux cas. Pour être complètement franc, vous pouvez en effet les utiliser sans distinction, simplement ma préférence serait pour tournure pour éviter tout manque de clarté possible. Par curiosité, qu'est-ce que le LBU?

Comment: [_Le bon usage_](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bon_Usage), Grevisse et Goosse, 1600 pp (14e éd.).